# Minimum polynom of an element in $K=\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2-2)$

Tags: finite-fields

I want to know how to calculate the minimum polynom of an element $\alpha$ in $K=\mathbb{F}_5[X]/(X^2-2)$ where $\alpha$ is the image on $K$ of $X+2$

I'm already verficated that $K$ is a field. As I know, the minimum polynom is $g$ with the smallest degree satisfying $g(\alpha)=0$.

In my notes there is an indication: If $f(X)=X^2-2$, calculate $f(X-2)$.

But I don't understand at all. I would very appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: what would be the image of $x+2$ in the field ?? what would be $f(x-2)$ then?

Comment: What are you meaning?

Comment: I am asking that : If $f(x)=x^2-2$ what would be $f(x-2)$

Comment: I think it's $x+4$

Comment: I do not understand this... I see $f(x)=x^2-2\Rightarrow f(x-2)=(x-2)^2-2=x^2-4x+4-2=x^2-4x+2$

Comment: Yes, but in $K$, $-4=1$ and $x^2=2$

Comment: Oh yeah... May be i am messing it up...

Comment: For all algebraic purposes that $X$ (or, more precisely, its coset $X+\langle X^2-2\rangle$) is $\sqrt2$. So in that sense the question is about finding the minimal polynomial of $2+X=2+\sqrt2$ over $\Bbb{F}_5$. Praphulla's got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $\beta$ for the residue class of $X$ in ${\mathbb F}_5[X]/(X^2-2)$, so we're looking at the field ${\mathbb F}_5[\beta]$. What is the minimum polynomial of $\beta$ over ${\mathbb F}_5$? (Trivial!)

Now $\alpha = \beta + 2$. So how do you now turn the minimum polynomial of $\beta$ into the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$? (This is what the hint tells you to do.)

Comment: So, the minimum polynom is simply $f(x-2)$?

Comment: Yes; if this is a exercise, you're probably expected to work this out, but that's it.

Comment: And do you know how to prove that $\alpha$ is primitive?

Comment: Well, that's a totally different question. I'd just compute $\alpha^{12}$ and show that that's $-1$.

Comment: Sorry for my question but... why 12? My notes say I have to prove $\alpha^{12}$ and $\alpha^{8}$ are different from $1$...

Comment: Well, you have to show that $\alpha$ generates ${\mathbb F}_{25}^*$, which is cyclic of order 24. So you could check it does not have order 2,3,4,6,8,12 (which is true if $\alpha^8$ and $\alpha^{12}$ are both not 1). But for a primitive element $\gamma$, you'd reach $-1$ halfway down the list $\gamma, \gamma^2, \dots, \gamma^{24}$: because $\gamma^{12}$ and $-1$ both have order 2 and there is only one element of order 2.